# How to mark prime(') symbol with subscript in matplotlib? (I want to express " p'_c "!)

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

My question seems easy but I can't handle it at all.

In MATLAB, I could use an expression of p'_c by `p'_{c}`,

but in matplotlib environment, `p{\prime}_{c}` continuously print out subscript of {c} away from {p'}.

How can I deal with this issue? Please check 'expression_example' file.
(quite hard to explain this stuff..)

[example_image_what_i_want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ5TU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not given your code it is difficult to know what you have tried or what it is used for (labels, titles, legends, text on plot). Do you use `r'$[insert here]$'`?

When I plot the following, it is shown as a superscript prime followed by subscript text without additional spacing.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,4,6,8,10]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title(r'$p^{\prime}_{c}$')
plt.xlabel(r'$p^{\prime}_{c}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$p^{\prime}_{c}$')
```

[Plot with superscript prime followed by subscript text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o30HY.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think the problem was caused by the following lines,
# matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'
# matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'STIXGeneral'
in order to change the font as similar as MATLAB font.
As I deleted those lines and applied your suggestion, I got the result what i want.